# How do I count occurrences of a word in a csv file using python?

Tags: python, list, file, append

So for my assignment I was giving a csv file and am supposed to print the number of people in the file, the amount of each type of email (.jp , .uk., etc.) and print the last names in the file that show up more than once. Whenever I run the program, it says there is 0 of each email type. What am I doing wrong?

I thought by using 'if " " in file" it would find each one and add it to "jp". Any suggestions?

`````
inFile = open('mydata.csv', 'r')

i = 0
jp = 0
uk = 0
de = 0

for line in inFile:
    i = i + 1
````
if '.jp' in inFile:
    jp = jp + 1
````
if '.uk' in inFile:
    uk = uk + 1
````
if '.de' in inFile:
    de = de + 1

print('There are', i - 1,'people in this file,')
print('There are', jp,'emails that end in .jp')
print('There are', uk,'emails that end in .uk')
print('There are', de,'emails that end in .de')

inFile.close()
outFile.close()
`````

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to include any imports and test data needed for it to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't iterating across the contents of the file for your `if` conditions.

```
for line in file:
   i = i + 1
   if '.jp' in line:
       ...
   if '.uk' in line:
       ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Im really new to this stuff so Ive been having a rough time with it. Cheers!